# How do you nest a paragraph of text within another paragraph?

Tags: luatex

What's the best way to recreate this InDesign-created text-within-text style in LaTeX (LuaTex)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a job for the [wrapfig package](https://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig?lang=en).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}\raggedright\setstretch{1.3}
            \textcolor{red}{\hrule height 2pt}

            \medskip

            \lipsum[2]

            \textcolor{red}{\hrule height 2pt}
\end{wrapfigure}
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.


\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image: wrapfigure wrapping]

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Lijishe Yes, but note that wrapfig have "some idiosyncrasies" (quoted from  the manual) that mean a tricky use sometimes. For instance, note that frabjous (+1)  not place the environment within the paragraph at random, but just in the natural end of a line.  The result could be bad with if some text  is added or removed before in the paragraph, if the paragraph is moved (added or removed contnet above, for instance)  or there are near lists. Not a big problem for a finished book, but could be annoying in a draft . You're warned.